# Product of diagonal entries of two symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix and $B=(b_{i,j})$ a negative semi-definite matrix. Then:

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij}$$

If a matrix is positive definite this means that $x^TAx>0$ for every $x \neq0$ and $x^TAx \leq 0$ for the negative semi-definite case.

---

My idea: Let $e_i$ be a vector that has $0$ as entries expect $1$ for the i-th entry, i.e., $e_1 = (1,0,0,\dots)$. Then $e_i^TAe_i = 0 \cdot a_{11} + \dots + 1 \cdot a_{ii} + 0 \cdot a_{nn} = a_{ii}$ and since $A$ is positive definite, $a_{ii}$ is positive and similarly for negative semi-definite case. Hence the sum over these diagonal entries is less or equal than $0$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Product of diagonal entries???

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct!

Using your proof, you can even claim stronger conclusion that each element of the product $a_{ii}b_{ii}$ shall be $\leq 0$.

Comment: One moment, I just realized that I only showed that the diagonal entries are postive/negative or 0. But that doesn't imply that the sum of the products is less or equal 0?

Comment: So you are interested in the sum $\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij}$ or the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}b_{ii}$ ?